# Depth first search, non-recursive approach

Tags: python, data-structures, charts, depth-first-search

I have implemented DFS using the recursive approach. However, my program breaks right after it is executed.

```
# Non Recursive approach
def Non_Recursive_dfs(graph, source):
    path = []
    stack = []
    stack.append(source)
    
    while stack:
        s = stack.pop()
        if s not in path:
            path.append(s)

        if s in path:
            #leaf node
            continue
        for neighbour in graph[s]:
            stack.append(neighbour)
    
    return " ".join(path)
```

Input and output:

```
print(Non_Recursive_dfs(graph, "A"))
O/p: A
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: The first if statement you have appends s to the path if it is not already in it. This guarantees that the code under the second if statement will always be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `if` statement guarantees that the code under the second one will always execute because it will add `s` to `path` if it is not already in it. You can simply change the second `if` statement to an `else-if` statement like so:

```
def Non_Recursive_dfs(graph, source):
    path = []
    stack = []
    stack.append(source)
    
    while stack:
        s = stack.pop()
        if s not in path:
            path.append(s)

        elif s in path:
            #leaf node
            continue
        for neighbour in graph[s]:
            stack.append(neighbour)
    
    return " ".join(path)
```

I quickly created some dummy data for `graph` and it seems to run fine.